# How to incorporate a dropdown link in my topnav

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I am working on a college assignment where I have to make a website. I built a top menu using flex box, however I am struggling to incorporate a dropdown navigation list in it. I know there are a milion of toturials that teach how to make these menus, however most of these toturials only build very simple menus without flex box and with some poor formating... I would like that when the user hovers over "Who are we" three links appear under the "Who are we".

I will now provide my html and css, along with some further description of the problem:

```
 <header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
            <li><img src="Logo.webp" alt="Logo" height="100px" width="100px"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Who Are We</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What Do We Do</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indicators</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* top menu */
.nav_links{
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.nav_links li{
  margin: 40px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav_links a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


.nav_links li a:hover{
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: beige;
}

.nav_links li a:visited{
  color: black;
}


nav ul li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

I know that the trick is to put a ul under the li that I want to dropdown, hide it, and only show it when the user hovers over it, but I cant get that to work. The dropdown navigation links always get so weird and out of place. I am stuck here for quite a few time, so if someone could help it would literally make my whole month!
Thanks.
(sorry if my english is weird it is not my first language). Also ignore the logo on my html, it is just a small image.

something like this:
[image]

Comment: Try looking at this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code, but you would need a little bit of javascript if you want a fully functional drop down menu

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* top menu */
.nav_links{
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.nav_links li{
  margin: 40px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav_links a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


.nav_links li a:hover{
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: beige;
}

.nav_links li a:visited{
  color: black;
}


nav ul li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 40px;
}
#who_are_we:hover + #drop_menu{
  display: block;
}
#drop_menu a{
  display: block
}
#drop_menu{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav_links">
            <li><img src="Logo.webp" alt="Logo" height="100px" width="100px"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" id="who_are_we">Who Are We</a>
              <div id="drop_menu">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                <a href="#">About us</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">What Do We Do</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indicators</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution was exactly what I was looking for! Your code works fine I only added this:  #drop_menu:hover{display: block;}  , so that the submenu is still shown when the user stops hovering the "WHO ARE WE" link, and added some padding to the submenu to my liking. Keep up the good work man!

Answer (score 0):

**I'm recode a css to like this, Dropdown after hover it.**

```css
.dropdownmenu ul, .dropdownmenu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropdownmenu ul {
    background: gray;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdownmenu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
}
.dropdownmenu a {
    background: #30A6E6;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font: bold 12px/20px sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
.dropdownmenu li:hover a {
    background: #000000;
}
#submenu {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
li:hover ul#submenu {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 40px;  /* adjust this as per top nav padding top & bottom comes */
    visibility: visible;
}
#submenu li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
#submenu a:hover {
    background: #DF4B05;
}
#submenu a {
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav class="dropdownmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><img src="Logo.webp" alt="Logo" height="100px" width="100px"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Who Are We</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Difference</a></li>
        <li><a href="">New features</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Creatinge</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">What Do We Do</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Indicators</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, however I wanted to keep my original menu and not a new one. However I appreciate it and I think your transitions are cool, I think I will implement them in my work! Thanks.